# Duplicate data from a synchronized data extension- Can't see the Syn DE in Automation studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automation

i'm working in Automation Studio in order to duplicate the data of synchronized DE into a new sendable DE. The problem I have is that **I see the synchronized DE in Contact Builder but I can't find it when I try to create the query** (the synchr DE folder is empty). 
Which could be the issue and how can I solve it?
In addition, as the sendable DE Id like to create should contain the list of all contacts i wonder which are the best option for creating the query: scheduling hourly with "add & update" is correct?
I'd really appreciate any best practice you'd like to share with me. thanks so much
Lucia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on right direction, when you try to create a query you won't find the synchronise DE's in query. But still you can specify the syncronized data extension name (in your case its contact so it will be like 'contact_salesforce') and query the records.

You can query it like :

```
SELECT * FROM Contact_Salesforce
```

If you are doing this from a child business unit, you'll need to add `.ent` as prefix.

```
SELECT * FROM ent.[Contact_Salesforce]
```

Yes, you can query with every one hour interval.

Regarding on action, if you keep 'update' action and if contact from salesforce has been deleted due to GDPR or some other process. The data will still be there in you contact data extension but not in syncronized data extension.

For these cases I would prefer 'overwrite' action over 'update' action.

Best practice for syncronized data source - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-contact-management/explore-synchronized-data-sources

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Naveen thanks so much for your answer, very clear and helpful. I wonder if you can please clarify which activity should I select in the automation? 
Kind regards

Comment: You are welcome @Giorgio !. Please mark it as a right answer. So that it helps others in future.

Comment: How can I mark it ? sorry I'm new in the community (and please if you have suggestion on automation tell me)

Comment: Hi Giorgia, Thanks for checking and no problem. Welcome to the community!. You can see the check mark sign next to my answer. Please select that one.